# how to disable select control's dropdown menu of nz-zorro-antd?

Tags: angular, select, tags

I am implementing one product in which I have integrated nz-zorro UI collection library.

I want to implement input control that can accept tags from user.
nz-zorro will provide me that kind of feature with `nz-select` control.

when we write tag and then hit enter will convert it like chip. check below gif :

[image]

But this control is select control so , it will open dropdown under the control which I don't want to open.

If anyone know about how to disable only dropdown, not input control, then please help me.

I  have **tried this code** :

```
<nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-control>
          <nz-select formControlName="tags" nzMode="tags" nzPlaceHolder="Add Keywords">
          </nz-select>
    </nz-form-control>
</nz-form-item>
```

I have also tried with custom dropdown template with `nzDropdownRender` option and keep template empty, but still dropdown is opening.

If anyone have any configuration about it then please mention here. it will saves my lot's of day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot's of time spending on this feature, I found the solution that we can hide dropdown using css.

After some documentation, I found custom dropdown Class directive in `nz-select` control which can hide dropdown menu from `select`.

Here Is my solution :

**component.ts:**

```
<nz-form-item>
  <nz-form-control>
      <nz-select formControlName="tags" nzDropdownClassName="hide-dropdown" nzMode="tags" nzPlaceHolder="Add Keywords">
      </nz-select>
  </nz-form-control>
</nz-form-item>
```

in global `style.css` :

```
.hide-dropdown {
   display: none;
 }
```

It will only allow to enter tags by typing. not from select options...